# Au-delà au sens de la profondeur

Tags: adverbes, indications-de-lieu

Il me semble que dans un contexte spatial *au-delà* se dit par rapport à un point sur une ligne (au-delà d'une borne kilométrique) ou à une ligne sur une surface (au delà de l'horizon). Y-a-t-il un adverbe de lieu ayant un rôle similaire dans le sens de la profondeur (xxxx de cette nappe phréatique)?

Answer (score 3):

C'est *deçà* qui s'oppose à *delà*.

Et cela vaut pour la verticalité comme pour l'horizontalité.

On aura donc *au delà* pour ce qui se trouve au-dessus (ou après) et ***en deçà*** pour ce qui se trouve en-dessous (ou avant)

Ainsi, au delà de la nappe phréatique on trouve la roche et en deçà de la nappe on trouve la couche d'argile.

De bons auteurs l'assurent... il en irait de même avec la Vérité par rapport aux Pyrénées...

Comment: Que veux-tu dire avec ta phrase sur les bons auteurs et les Pyrénées ? J'ai du mal à comprendre.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat «Vérité en deçà des Pyrénées, erreur au-delà», formule proverbiale proposée initialement par Pascal (un bon auteur assurément), qui indique la relativité de la vérité. Ici, deux peuples (français et espagnol) risquent de ne pas toujours parvenir aux mêmes conclusions, la manière de résoudre un certain problème pouvant diverger très tôt dans l'analyse (importance plus ou moins grande accordée à certains de ses aspects, valeurs sociales, etc.) et aboutir à des conclusions antithétiques.

Comment: @Montéedelait : Dans mes bras!... Abraracourcix! http://chasseautresor-ng.0707a.net/SandBox/dans-mes-bras.png ;-) ... et, très respectueusement, merci encore une fois.

Answer (score 2):

Les locutions **au-dessous** et **au-dessus** sont utilisés pour désigner les zones situées de part et d'autre d'une limite, dans le sens vertical. **En dessous/en-dessus** sont aussi utilisés avec le même sens.

> Au-dessous de cette nappe phréatique, on trouve une couche d'argile.

Note: **dessus** et **dessous** se situent par rapport à un objet ou un lieu et ont comme axe celui de la pesanteur (donc la verticale) alors qu'**au-delà** a pour référence une frontière quelconque et comme axe tout chemin allant de l'intérieur (**en deçà**, souvent l'endroit où l'on se situe, mais pas forcément) vers l'extérieur de cette dernière (**au-delà**).

*Au-delà* peut donc se situer au-dessous, au-dessus ou sensiblement au même niveau que le lieu qui sert de limite (au-delà de la nappe phréatique lors d'un forage, au-delà du deuxième étage de la tour Eiffel, au delà du no man's land).

Quelques adverbes utilisent aussi ***outre-*** avec le sens d'au-delà : Outre-Manche, outre-Atlantique, outre-Rhin, outre-Quiévrain...

Comment: Au vu des "scores" actuels, je vote pour cette réponse afin qu'elle ne finisse pas au fond de la pile alors qu'elle répond aussi très bien à la demande de l'OP.

Answer (score 1):

Un terme assez souvent employé dans ce contexte, en particulier en géologie est « **sous-jacent** » ; il devrait aussi convenir en ce qui concerne les profondeurs marines, cela au vu d'un exemple à l'entrée pour le terme terme correspondent dans le TLFi, « **[sus-jacent](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sus-jacent)** ».

> Il y a donc, sur le fond et à son voisinage immédiat, une activité bactérienne généralement plus importante qu'à aucun autre niveau des eaux sus-jacentes (J.-M. Pérès, Vie océan, 1966, p. 16).

La définition suivante du TLFi et ses exemples indique cet usage;

> A. − [En parlant d'une chose concr.] Qui est situé en dessous. Synon. inférieur, subjacent.Couche, roche sous-jacente. L'eau s'infiltrait dans de certains terrains sous-jacents, particulièrement friables (Hugo, Misér., t. 2, 1862, p. 548).Un réseau sous-jacent de filets liquides qui, par quelque faille souterraine, devaient s'épancher vers la rivière (Verne, Île myst., 1874, p. 46).
>   − Littér. Sous-jacent à.Les sables qui dans une partie du bassin parisien tantôt surmontent les calcaires et tantôt leur sont sous-jacents (Vidal de La Bl., Princ. géogr. hum., 1921, p. 183).

Pour le cas que vous citez on devrait donc dire « au niveau sous-jacent **à** cette nappe phréatique »

Comment: La question précise *adverbe*, sous-jacent est un *adjectif*.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vrai, il s'agit là d'adjectifs ; ne pourrait-on pas cependant étendre le concept d'adverbe en tant que mot ou locution et considérer que si l'on pas exactement un adverbe certaines des expressions qui résultent de combinaisons avec ces adjectifs et que l'on appelle syntagmes adverbiaux, remplissent la même fonction grammaticale? Une explication de cela (qui n'a pas été faite) suffirait-elle à légitimer suffisamment la réponse?